# read_file 'File::Slurp' - sysopen: No such file or directory

Tags: perl, readfile, fileslurp

What could be wrong here?

I am trying to display the content of an **existing** file:

```
perl -MFile::Slurp -e 'print File::Slurp->read_file("/tmp/001.jpg", { binmode => ":raw" } ) if -e "/tmp/001.jpg"; '
```

and I get the error:

```
read_file 'File::Slurp' - sysopen: No such file or directory
```

The file exists, the `print` gets executed only `if -e "/tmp/001.jpg"`

Comment: Your use of `-e` might be ambiguous without parentheses.  So, try `if (-e "/tmp/001.jpg")`

Comment: same result with parantheses :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the function via `File::Slurp::read_file` instead of `File::Slurp->read_file`. In the latter case Perl's object system comes into play, and the first argument passed to `read_file` will be the thing before the `->` -- meaning its first argument will be the string `"File::Slurp"` instead of the file name you actually want to read.

That's also why you call `new` on the packages you want to create a new instance from.

Comment: Actually, `-MFile::Slurp` will export the `read_file` function, so you don't need the `File::Slurp::` part at all.  (It won't hurt, though.)